# NSFetchRequest doesn't give back anything

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am trying to get all the pictures of an album. I am getting this by an webservice. The webservice has the following layout.

```
{

    "name": "Club Brugge - KRC Genk",
    "date": "08.10.2012",
    "albumId: 1,
    "pictures": [
        {
            "pic_album_id"=1,
            "pic_id" = 1,
            "url": "http://www.krcgenk.be/images/gallery/album_199/800X600/1a06dc0e405fd0219e3d327f1eec7fbf.jpg"
        },
        {
            "pic_album_id"=1,
            "pic_id" = 2,
            "url": "http://www.krcgenk.be/images/gallery/album_199/800X600/e8e10c0664eb0533a0534ed69891b165.jpg"
        },
        {
            "pic_album_id"=1,
            "pic_id"= 3,
            "url": "http://www.krcgenk.be/images/gallery/album_199/800X600/750b55a87b8eae33b8f3278add9bec44.jpg"
        }
]
```

I have the following functions to get all pictures of a certain album.

```
 - (NSMutableArray *)getAllPicturesOfAlbumId: (int)AlbumId
    {
        NSString *picture_Url = [[NSString alloc]init];
        NSArray *results = [[NSArray alloc]init];
        _picturesForAlbum = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        picture_Url = @"";
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pic_album_id == %@",
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:AlbumId]];
        NSLog(@"album id: %@",[NSNumber numberWithInt:AlbumId]);
        [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Picture" inManagedObjectContext:self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext]];
        [request setPredicate:predicate];
        NSError *error = nil;
        results = [self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        NSLog(@"results: %@",results);
        if (results == nil) {
            NSLog(@"nil results");
            // handle errors
        } else if (results.count == 0) {
            NSLog(@"0 results");
// nothing found
        } else {
            for(int i = 0; i < results.count ; i++){
            Picture *picture = [results objectAtIndex:i];
                NSLog(@"%@",[results objectAtIndex:i]);
                [_picturesForAlbum addObject:picture];
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"%@",_picturesForAlbum);
        //NSLog(@"album: %@",[_picturesForAlbum objectAtIndex:5]);
        return _picturesForAlbum;
    }
```

The code above, gives the following log. (I gave for testcase AlbumId = 3 with it)

```
2012-10-12 14:53:04.577 RacingGenk[4793:c07] album id: 3
2012-10-12 14:53:04.578 RacingGenk[4793:c07] results: (
)
2012-10-12 14:53:04.578 RacingGenk[4793:c07] (
)
```

Hope anybody can help me.

Kind regards.

** Here you see a [screenshot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/74322780@N08/8079761729/in/photostream) of my database model

**EDIT**

Here you see how I get my pictures and put it in my database.

```
+ (Picture *)pictureWithGenkInfo:(NSDictionary *)genkInfo
          inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
                     withAlbumId:(int)albumId
                   withPictureId:(int)pictureId;
{

    Picture *picture = nil;

    picture = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Picture"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
    picture.url                     = [genkInfo objectForKey:PICTURES_URL];
    picture.pic_album_id            = [NSNumber numberWithInt:albumId];
    picture.picture_id              = [NSNumber numberWithInt:pictureId];


    return picture;
}
```

//The method above is called in my first controller that comes one screen.  With this loop I fill up my core data-base.

```
 for (NSDictionary *genkInfo in albums ) {
                albumId++;
                [Album albumWithGenkInfo:genkInfo inManagedObjectContext:document.managedObjectContext withAlbumId:albumId];
                 for (NSDictionary *genkInfo2 in pictures ) {
                     pictureId++;
                     [Picture pictureWithGenkInfo:genkInfo2 inManagedObjectContext:document.managedObjectContext withAlbumId:albumId withPictureId:pictureId];
                 }
               pictureId = 0;
                // table will automatically update due to NSFetchedResultsController's observing of the NSMOC
            }
```

Comment: It's very strange, you ar fetching results from Picture entity, but using in predicate album ID. I think in predicate should be: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"album.pic_album_id == %@",  numberWithInt:AlbumId]];

Comment: I'm sorry I had the wrong json data provided. I've edited my code.

Comment: Do you have Album entity? This entity should have Picture one to many  relationship. Then you can get all picuture just call -> NSArray *pictures = [album.pictures allObjects];

Comment: wheres the bit where you import the data to your NSManagedObject Subclasses? It doesn't really matter what the JSON is when you're searching with core data. Post a screenshot of your `NSManagedObjectModel`. You can always inspect the contents of your SQL database with a free app, or even use an XML persistent store while at this stage of development.

Comment: All your pictures say they have an album id of '1', so getting no '3' results may be correct (if your data sample is accurate).

Comment: I added a screenshot where you can see my database model.

Comment: Try `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whichAlbum.album_id == %@", ...]`.

Comment: @NeverBe: I think you were on the right track with your first comment, only that the exact names of the attributes and relationships were not known at that time. Don't you want to post an answer?

Comment: @MartinR, i did, hope it help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use predicate

```
 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whichAlbum.album_id == %d", AlbumId];
```

**UPDATE**

```
 for (NSDictionary *genkInfo in albums ) {
      albumId++;
      Album *album = [Album albumWithGenkInfo:genkInfo inManagedObjectContext:document.managedObjectContext withAlbumId:albumId];
      for (NSDictionary *genkInfo2 in pictures ) {
          pictureId++;
          Picture *pic = [Picture pictureWithGenkInfo:genkInfo2 inManagedObjectContext:document.managedObjectContext withAlbumId:albumId withPictureId:pictureId];
          [album addPictureObject:pic]; // this method should be automatically generated
       }
       pictureId = 0;
 // table will automatically update due to NSFetchedResultsController's observing of the NSMOC
        }

// don't forget save context
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but when I put logs in my code. It gives me the log of "0 results". Any idea ?

Comment: I assume that something is wrong with the parser. Could you attach code of parser here?

Comment: What do you mean by the parser ?

Comment: it's only part of parser. I want to see how you are processing full  json file.

Comment: When I looked again, I saw that it is always giving me back the same results? Any idea ?

Comment: same results for different albumID?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18101/discussion-between-stef-geelen-and-neverbe)

Answer (score 0):

How to troubleshoot:

Get yourself [Liya](https://itunes.apple.com/app/liya/id455484422?mt=12) or another sqlite database viewer. Navigate to the folder with the core data database. On the simulator that would be

`/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<version of iOS>/Applications/<long cryptig string>/<folder-with-the-core-data-database>`

Open the `sqlite` database, navigate to the `ZPicture` table and check that data is present. 
If there is no data then the the `webservice` -> `core-data` program logic has a problem.

If there is data and it appears to be good go back to Xcode and enable logging for the core-data request. Edit the scheme (Product - Edit scheme), select the `Run, Debug` scheme and change the tab to `Arguments`. In the field `Arguments Passed On Launch` add `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3`. Ensure the check box is ticked.

Run your app and in the debugger console window there should be the sql code generated by core-data.

You will see something similar to: (you might see the `whichAlbum` showing up)

```
<timestamp> CoreData: annotation: fetch using NSSQLiteStatement <0xfxxxxxx> on entity
'Picture' with sql text 'SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.zpic_album_id 
FROM zpicture t0 WHERE t0.zpic_album_id == ?'
<timestamp> CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = (int64)3
```

Take the sql command, return to Liya and paste the command into the `Run Custom Command` field. Replace the question mark in

```
   t0.zpic_album_id == ?
```

with the `album_id` you want to see.

The result of the query will be what Core Data will retrieve.

Not sure where the `whichAlbum` would go. Just come back with your finding and let us know.